# ASP.NET Impersonation with more than one account

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I'm using a Windows 2008 server with IIS 7.0 and am able to Enable ASP.NET Impersonation on my Web Application in IIS.  My problem is that I'm only able to enable it for one account (from what I can tell).  How can I add multiple accounts to the ASP.NET Impersonation?

Thanks

Comment: You simply can´t, because how should be distinguished which account to run now. You can it install multiple times in multiple application pools.

Comment: Are you trying to impersonate whatever account the user is? That is certainly possible.

Comment: I was hoping to allow only a few users the ability to log into the website.  This is a machine that is in the Cloud and not on our network in the office so I wasn't really sure how to go about this.  Any ideas?